# Form is returning value 1 on submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have some content and a table inside my `<form>` tags. On submitting, when I `echo` the post value coming from the form, it shows the value `1` against each entered value.

This surprises me and I would like to know why this is happening?
Even when I have commented out all of my CSS and JavaScript linked libraries/files, a `1` is still returned.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <form method="post" action="save_view.php"> <textarea id="header">INVOICE</textarea>
        <div id="identity">
            <div> <img id="image" src="images/logo_1.png" alt="logo" /> </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div id="customer">
            <table id="meta">
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                    <td> <input name="Invoice" type="text" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Customer Name</td>
                    <td> <input name="cname" type="text" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Paid Date</td>
                    <td> <input name="pdate" type="text" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Sales Person</td>
                    <td> <input name="sperson" type="text" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>
</div>
```

**save_view.php**:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $invoice = isset($_POST['Invoice']);
    die();
}
```

Comment: You're asking to echo the result of isset() which is a boolean. Since your value is true => it echoes 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isset` returns a boolean.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $invoice = isset($_POST['Invoice']) ? $_POST['Invoice'] : '';
    echo ($invoice);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhh !!
Thanxxxxxxx

Answer (score 3):

**[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

To get value you have to use like this

```
 if(isset($_POST['Invoice']){
   echo $invoice = $_POST['Invoice'];
}
die();
```

You got TRUE every time and that's the reason you got only 1 everytime

Comment: Ohhhhhhh !!
Thanxxxxxxx

Answer (score 3):

**[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** method is for determinate if a variable exist.

So when you do `$invoice = isset($_POST['Invoice']);`

```
$invoice = 1 //variable exist

$invoice =0 //variable not exist
```

Try

```
if(isset($_POST['Invoice']))
   echo  $invoice = $_POST['Invoice'];
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhh !!
Thanxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

isset() always returns either true or false, echo your data like this

```
echo"<pre>";print_r($_POST['Invoice']);die;
```